# Bonding gas line to electrical Ground

Tags: grounding-and-bonding

When bonding a gas line to a electrical ground, can the bond to the gas line be anywhere post meter or does it have to be close to the meter?

Answer (score 0):

NEC 250.104.B. Requires bonding, the bond can be made from the service panel, ground rods the bond has to be accessible and is required at the entrance to the house.250.68.C.1
The inspectors like the bond within 5’ of entering the home or at the meter most meters are at the entrance but not all. The conductor is sized According to 250.122 so you want it to be close to the service.

Comment: I would suggest checking with your local inspector. This has changed several times in my area over the last 20 years.

Answer (score 0):

The metallic gas pipe system in the house can be bonded at any convenient point on the "grounding electrode system". That said, most such pipe systems are effectively bonded by the equipment grounding conductors included with the electrical supplies to the devices hooked up to the gas pipes, and do not require any further bonding.